# Is there a way in openpyxl to access a worksheet from a cell?

Tags: python, excel, class, openpyxl

If I have a cell object, is it possible to do something like:

```
theWorksheet = cell.worksheet
```

I tried doing that, but it gave an error.

Comment: cell object does have a.worksheet. What exactly do you want to access?

Comment: I'm trying to grab the worksheet's title from the cell. I thought I could just do cell.worksheet.title? Tells me the "cell" object does not have an object "worksheet"

Answer (score 0):

Should be `parent` property:

```
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
cell = ws.cell(row=15, column=15)
print(cell.parent.title)
```